# LINQ query fails for NULL values

Tags: linq, ado.net, dataset, linq-to-dataset

```
var query = from t1 in Table1
            join t2 in Table2
                on new { t1.Id }
                equals new { t2.Id}
            select new
            {
                t1.Id,
                t1.FirstName,
                t1.MiddleName,//allows null values in the database
                t1.LastName,
                t1.phone //allows null values in the database

            };
if(query.Count()>0)//fails here"The value for column MiddleName in table'Table1' is DBNULL"
{
}
```

Is there a way in which I can get all the rows including null values for middleName and Phone in my LINQ query?

Comment: what's the data type for "MiddleName" and "phone"?

Comment: `Table1` and `Table2` are `DataTable`s right, you're not using Linq to SQL?

Comment: Why do you join on T2?  You never use it, did you already filter down the set?

Comment: I am just trying to simplify the query. I am using fields from the other table. Yes both table1 and table2 are data tables.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using linq-to-datasets you must manually convert nullable columns to null because their value in `DataRow` is `DBNull.Value`. In strongly typed DataSet you should be able to do something like:

```
var query = from t1 in Table1
        join t2 in Table2
            on new { t1.Id }
            equals new { t2.Id}
        select new
        {
            t1.Id,
            t1.FirstName,
            t1.IsMiddleNameNull ? null : t1.MiddleName,
            t1.LastName,
            t1.IsPhoneNull ? null : t1.Phone 
        };
```

In untyped DataSet you will call something like `t1.IsNull("MiddleName") ? null : t1["MiddleName"]`

Comment: This is what I get.......Error 11:Invalid anonymous type member declarator. Anonymous type members must be declared with a member assignment, simple name or member access.

Comment: Yes, that is the problem with anonymous type. It cannot infer type from `null`.

Comment: If you want to use anonymous type you should wrap the conditional code to custom property. Add partial class to your strongly typed DataRow and expose properties like MiddleNameNullable and PhoneNullable.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the metadata is out of sync with your DB schema. It seems as if when the classes were generated for your schema MiddleName was not nullable, but now it is. If that's the case, you need to refresh your EDMX if you're using Entity Framework or refresh your classes if you're using LINQ to SQL.

Comment: I don't think that's the problem.

Comment: Ok, well you're not providing enough information to help you so this is my guess based off of the problem you're having. LINQ is a generic technology, you need to provide more details on what provider you're using (Entity Framework? LINQ2SQL? pure objects?) and also posting a full stack trace of your exception would help a lot more.

Comment: Error :The value for column 'MiddleName' in table 'Table1' is DBNull.

Comment: I believe Ladislav's answer is the right one at this point. Did you try that?

Answer (score 0):

Could you please give this a shot

```
var query = from t1 in Table1
            join t2 in Table2
                on new { t1.Id }
                equals new { t2.Id}
            select new
            {
                Id = t1.Id,
                FirstName = t1.FirstName,
                MiddleName = t1.MiddleName,//allows null values in the database
                LastName = t1.LastName,
                Phone = t1.phone //allows null values in the database

            };
if(query.Count()>0)//fails here"The value for column MiddleName in table'Table1' is DBNULL"
{
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that a new anonymous object has its properties defined on-the-fly with types inferred from the values.

In such a line

```
MiddleName = t1.MiddleName,//allows null values in the database
```

a new property called MiddleName is created whose type is t1.MiddleName's type. But if t1.MiddleName is null, what is the type ??? Null has no type.

To prevent any ambiguousity simply put

```
MiddleName = (string)t1.MiddleName,
```

to let the compiler know that anyway it's a string, even if not provided.